# PHP Script Cannot Receive Data from axios's Request in Redux Action Function

Tags: php, redux, axios, redux-promise

I want to sent some data to a php script with the use of `redux` and `promise` as if the following.

```
export function fetchFileContent() {
    return {
        type: "FETCH_FILECONTENT",
        payload: axios.post("/api/ide/read-file.php", {
            filePath: document.getArgByIndex(0)[0]
        })
    };
}
```

But the php script cannot receive the data. When I print all the data in `$_POST` using `var_dump`. There is nothing inside.

I checked the **Request Payload** in the Google Chrome debugging tool and it seems no problem.
[image]

In my php script:

```
if (isset($_POST["filePath"])) 
    echo "yes"; 
else 
    echo "no";
echo "I am the correct file";
var_dump($_POST["filePath"]);

$dir = $_POST['filePath'];
echo $_POST['filePath'];
```

And I got this response:

```
noI am the correct file<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: filePath in <b>/var/www/html/api/ide/read-file.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />
NULL
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: filePath in <b>/var/www/html/api/ide/read-file.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: filePath in <b>/var/www/html/api/ide/read-file.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />
```

How can I get back the data in the php script?

Comment: Are you definitely checking the right php file? If you're seeing it being sent in your network tab then there isn't any reason it shouldn't be sending.

Comment: @RossWilson - If I modify the script like adding `if (isset($_POST["filePath"])) echo "yes"; else echo "no";`, I can see `no`. If I add `echo "I am the correct file";`, I can also see it in the response.

Comment: When you do `var_dump($_POST);`, what do you see? It looks like axios is sending a JSON object, so you might need to run json_decode on your $_POST array.

Comment: @ChrisForrence - When I do `var_dump($_POST)`, I got `array(0) {}`.

Comment: If its JSON you need to get it from php://input like so: 
`$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);`

Comment: @MattAltepeter - You are correct! Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thank to Matt Altepeter and his comment, I finally solved by adding the line:

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

So if I do a `var_dump($_POST)` now, I can get the data `filePath`.

```
array(1) {
  ["filePath"]=>
  string(10) "/I am here"
}
```